После установки AndroidStudio не работает часть импорта и анотаций, как починить?
Установил Андройд студию на Ubuntu, пути к JDK всё правильно указан (проверял в интеледжи идеи) но после индексации проекта часть импортов указывается как недоступные, соответственно часть аннотация не работает. Как починить непонятно. Чистил кэш проекта, проверял пути к SDK и прочее.


